# Ruby debugger opens on kernel_require.rb not file specified

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-debug

I'm working through Beginning Ruby and am doing the first exercise with the debugger. It has me running `ruby -r debug debug_test.rb`. The debugger *does* launch, but *not* on the file I specified (I've tried several). Instead I get:

```
Debug.rb
Emacs support available.

/home/henry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:57: RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.enter
```

I'm not really sure the implications of this, and google provides no insight. In any case, I thought this might be of some use:

```
(rdb:1) list
[52, 61] in /home/henry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   52      if Gem::Specification.unresolved_deps.empty? then
   53        begin
   54          RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.exit
   55          return gem_original_require(path)
   56        ensure
=> 57          RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.enter
   58        end
   59      end
   60  
   61      # If +path+ is for a gem that has already been loaded, don't
(rdb:1) var local
  found_specs => nil
  le => nil
  load_error => nil
  names => nil
  path => "debug"
  spec => nil
  valid => nil
(rdb:1)
```

While debug_test.rb does not require any gems, considering the mention of rubygems I thought my rvm gemset might be causing the problems. To this end I tried repeating the procedure with newly created (empty) gemset, but the problem persists. After this I tried running with a different version of ruby (1.9.3), where again the error persists. Interestingly it seems that for 1.9.3 the file does not exist:

```
/home/henry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:57:
(rdb:1) list
[52, 61] in /home/henry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
No sourcefile available for /home/henry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I installed ruby-1.9.3-p448 by rbenv on Mac, and encountered the same issue as you. I have no idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing this currently 1.9.3p448 with There are many things going on here that may be conspiring against you.

It is sad that *Beginning Ruby* recommends using this debugger. I bet just about any other one you use, ruby-debug, pry, byebug, trepan won't have this feature. I suppose *Beginning Ruby* recommends that module because "debug.rb" comes with Ruby, but it is by far not a debugger one would use as a primary debugger.

And then Ruby has changed over time in the way it handles requires. So probably when Beginning Ruby was written (what is the copyright of the edition you are using?) this feature didn't exist, but now it does. I am pretty sure that if you go back to Ruby 1.8 you won't see this. Probably if you go forward to Ruby 2.x you won't see this either.